# How can I group 3 tables together in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, relation

Let's assume that we have 3 tables: product, organization, advert

`product.sql`

```sql
CREATE TABLE product (
    name             VARCHAR   NOT NULL,
    id               BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    advert_id        BIGINT    NOT NULL REFERENCES advert(id),
    organization_id  BIGINT    NOT NULL REFERENCES organization(id)
);
```

`organization.sql`

```sql
CREATE TABLE organization (
    name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    id   BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
);
```

`advert.sql`

```sql
CREATE TABLE advert (
    title  VARCHAR,
    id     BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
);
```

In the end I want to have JSON structure like this

```json
{
    id: "ADVERT_ID",
    title: "ADVERT_TITLE",
    products: [
        { 
            id: "PRODUCT_ID",
            advert_id: "ADVERT_ID",
            organization: { 
                id: "ORGANIZATION_ID", 
                name: "ORGANIZATION_NAME" 
            }, 
            product: { 
                id: "PRODUCT_ID", 
                name: "PRODUCT_NAME"
            },
       },
       { 
            id: "PRODUCT_ID", 
            advert_id: "ADVERT_ID",
            organization: { 
                id: "ORGANIZATION_ID", 
                name: "ORGANIZATION_NAME" 
            }, 
            product: { 
                id: "PRODUCT_ID", 
                name: "PRODUCT_NAME"
            }
       }
    ]
}
```

And let's say when the offers array is empty, I don't want to get a JSON array like this:

```js
[null]
```

Thank you very much!

### EDIT

After doing some more research and trying to make a prototype in Sequelize, I was able to achieve this:

```js
{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Buy from Hot Fries Inc. today!',
  createdAt: '2021-07-07T18:17:39.723Z',
  updatedAt: '2021-07-07T18:17:39.723Z',
  Products: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'French Fries',
      org_id: 1,
      adv_id: 1,
      createdAt: '2021-07-07T18:17:39.726Z',
      updatedAt: '2021-07-07T18:17:39.726Z',
      Organization: {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Hot Fries Inc.',
        createdAt: '2021-07-07T18:17:39.713Z',
        updatedAt: '2021-07-07T18:17:39.713Z'
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I have chosen Sequelize to quickly see the logs of the queries that were going on undercover and here's what I discovered:

```sql
 SELECT "Advert".*,
       "products"."id"                      AS "Products.id",
       "products"."name"                    AS "Products.name",
       "products"."org_id"                  AS "Products.org_id",
       "products"."adv_id"                  AS "Products.adv_id",
       "products"."createdat"               AS "Products.createdAt",
       "products"."updatedat"               AS "Products.updatedAt",
       "Products->Organization"."id"        AS "Products.Organization.id",
       "Products->Organization"."name"      AS "Products.Organization.name",
       "Products->Organization"."createdat" AS "Products.Organization.createdAt"
       ,
       "Products->Organization"."updatedat" AS
       "Products.Organization.updatedAt"
FROM   (SELECT "Advert"."id",
               "Advert"."name",
               "Advert"."createdat",
               "Advert"."updatedat"
        FROM   "adverts" AS "Advert"
        LIMIT  1) AS "Advert"
       LEFT OUTER JOIN "products" AS "Products"
                    ON "Advert"."id" = "products"."adv_id"
       LEFT OUTER JOIN "organizations" AS "Products->Organization"
                    ON "products"."org_id" = "Products->Organization"."id";
```

This is the way that Sequelize joined sub-tables, if it's called that way.

Comment: Advert seems to have no any references to/from other two tables.

Comment: how do `advert` and `product` relate?

Comment: Oh sorry my bad, updated it

Comment: There are functions `to_json()`, `row_to_json()`, `json_build_object()` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html and aggregates `json_agg()`, `json_object_agg()` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I knew about `row_to_json()` and `json_agg()` but didn't know about the other ones. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a combination of `jsonb_build_object` and some subqueries is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT 
  jsonb_build_object(
    'id',a.id,
    'title',a.title,
    'products',(SELECT json_agg(
                  jsonb_build_object(
                    'id',p.id,
                    'advert_id',a.id,
                    'organization',jsonb_build_object(
                                      'id',o.id,
                                      'name',o.name),
                     'product',json_build_object(
                                 'id',p.id,
                                 'name',p.name)                   
                    ))
                FROM product p
                JOIN organization o ON o.id = p.organization_id
                WHERE p.advert_id = a.id)
  )
FROM advert a;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. May I ask if there's a cleaner and easier way to do it?

Comment: @krx3122 certainly there are other ways to do it.. but clean and easy are pretty much subjective when it comes to code ;)

Comment: Hey again Jim. Can you please check out my updated question? I have included some testing details with Sequelize. I have included the query that it made(that can be improved and cleaned up). What do you think about that one? Note that some fields in the json are autogenerated

Comment: @krx3122 the query looks ok. Unfortunately I cannot test its performance, as I just have the short version of your create table statements and have no data. I prepared a fiddle, so that you can test it yourself: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=69d2c2e54f393b08700d2c8e00ad8de2

Comment: Hey, (answering you from my original account) alright, thanks for the answer!